# Determine if each page in PDF has the same height

Tags: bash, pdf, resize, flash

I use the following code to convert swf books to pdf:

```
swftopdf () {
    if [ ! -f "$1.pdf" ]; then
        wget "http://content.yudu.com/android/dJcuwVV99lEgqWoc/content/$1.high";
        mimetype=$(file $1.high --mime-type);
        if [ "$mimetype" == "$1.high: application/x-shockwave-flash" ]; then
            swfrender -Y 2500 "$1.high" -o "$1.png"; convert "$1.png" "$1.pdf";
        else
            convert "$1.high[x2500]" "$1.pdf";
        fi;
        rm -rf $1.high; rm -rf $1.png;
    fi;
};
for i in {1..244}; do
    while [ ! -f "$i.pdf" ]; do
        swftopdf $i;
    done;
done;
filelist=$(ls|sort -n);
pdftk $filelist cat output '/home/shane/Desktop/Complete Ebooks/Secondary Level/Leaving Cert/Folens/Othello.pdf' compress; rm -rf *.pdf
```

Rarely, the .high file would be a jpg rather than a swf, hence why there's the else convert "$i1.high[x2500]" segment. However, I didn't initially have [x2500] written there.

So, what I'm wondering is, rather than deleting all the books I've already converted,
 **is there any way of figuring out if any of the pages has a height which differs to 2500 in the large pdf** (the .high's, .png's and individual .pdf's are already deleted), so I can then delete and reconvert that book, so that the jpg pages have a height of 2500 too?
Thanks


Also, if anyone knows a less convoluted way of doing this, I'd appreciate it if they told me it


If you need an example of 1 page being a .swf, and another being a .jpg, for explanatory purposes:
http://content.yudu.com/android/dJcuwVV99lEgqWoc/content/1.high - swf
http://content.yudu.com/android/dJcuwVV99lEgqWoc/content/2.high - jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have ImageMagick installed, you can use `identify` to answer the question whether all pages are of the same height. Here is an example of an arbitrarily choosen PDF:

```
> identify MyFile.pdf 
MyFile.pdf[0] PDF 524x751 524x751+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 49.6KB 0.050u 0:00.050
MyFile.pdf[1] PDF 524x751 524x751+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 49.6KB 0.050u 0:00.050
MyFile.pdf[2] PDF 524x751 524x751+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 49.6KB 0.050u 0:00.040
```

Don't be surprised if the output of `identify` doesn't tell a height of 2500: Your example JPG file has a resolution of 149 ppi. PDF usually takes 72dpi. So I'd expect your converted JPG to have a height of 1208 (= 2500 * 72/149):

```
> convert 2.high[x2500] 2.pdf
> identify 2.pdf

2.pdf PDF 870x1208 870x1208+0+0 16-bit Bilevel DirectClass 132KB 0.010u 0:00.000
```

Hope that helps...